# WalletConnect with Ethers.js not working

Tags: ethers.js, react, walletconnect

I've been attempting to get WalletConnect to work on my React site, with no luck. I have followed the basic implementation from the website, as follows, but nothing happens, I don't see a pop-up or anything:

```
let web3Provider;

//  Create WalletConnect Provider
const provider = new WalletConnectProvider({
  infuraId: "<INFURA ID>",
});

async function launchQRPopup() {
    // assuming it should launch a pop up here
    await provider.enable()
    .then(function() {
        web3Provider = new providers.Web3Provider(provider);
    })
}
```

I'm not getting any errors at all. Nothing happens. I'm at a loss for how to connect it. The idea is to allow people to connect their mobile wallets to the desktop app in order to mint tokens, but I've hit a dead end. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try checking the console to see if there are any printed issues? Maybe it will tell you something like "can't run .enable on undefined". Also, I might be wrong but I'm not sure you can mix await and then like that. Maybe remove the `then` clause and see if you get the WC popup.

Comment: Hi Kenzo, you're right – I've removed the ```then``` function and now I'm getting the error you mentioned above: "App.js:146 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'enable')". Any suggestions as to how I may resolve that? Thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: You're welcome. This error indicates that "provider" is null, which means that because of JS variable scoping, the provider you previously declared is not accessible as-is in the launchQRPopup function. To fix it, you can move the provider declaration to inside launchQRPopup. Alternatively, it might work if you do `this.provider` instead of `provider` inside launchQRPopup, but I'm not sure, my JS is rusty :)